# Building cocos2d-x android project failed: Unknown EABI object attribute 44

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, cocos2d-x

Today, I use `cygwin` and `ndk-r8` to cross-build my cocos2d-x android project:HelloCpp, I fail and get some errors like:

```
Unknown EABI object attribute 44
```

Here are the messages from cygwin:

```
StaticLibrary  : libcocos2d.a
SharedLibrary  : libhellocpp.so
E:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: Warning: ./obj/local/armeabi/webp.a(alpha.o): Unknown EABI object attribute 44
E:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: Warning: ./obj/local/armeabi/webp.a(buffer.o): Unknown EABI object attribute 44
```

I have found some tips on the web, and some guys say that's the problem of ndk's toolchains.But I don't know what to do , does any one who is studying cocos2d-x have the same problem as me?I really hope some one can give me guidance.

Answer (score 4):

The toolchain you're using doesn't understand the attribute and is ignoring it. Try to update ndk-r9b to avoid that Warning.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Android NDK R8 on Windows. Normally I work on Mac but in my Windows I use the android-ndk-r8c version because I have troubles with the other version when try to compile.

Try to download another NDK (r8c) and try again.